# matplotlib smooth animation superimposed on scatter plot

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot, interactive

The following Python code in Jupyter shows an example that displays some generated scatter plot data, and it superimposes a line that you can interactively change the y intercept and slope, It also displays the root mean square error. My question is this: How can I make it more responsive? there is a lag and an accumulation of changes that get processed, and it flickers a lot. Can it be faster and more responsive and smoother?

///

```
%matplotlib inline

from ipywidgets import interactive
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Desired mean values of generated sample.
N = 50

# Desired mean values of generated sample.
mean = np.array([0, 0])

# Desired covariance matrix of generated sample.
cov = np.array([
        [ 10,  8],
        [  8, 10]
    ])

# Generate random data.
data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, size=N)
xdata = data[:, 0]
ydata = data[:, 1]

# Plot linear regression line
def f(m, b):
    plt.figure()
    x = np.linspace(-10, 10, num=100)
    plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'ro')
    plt.plot(x, m * x + b)
    plt.ylim(-10, 10)
    rmes = np.sqrt(np.mean(((xdata*m+b)-ydata)**2))
    print("Root Mean Square Error: ", rmes)

interactive_plot = interactive(f, m=(-10.0, 10.0), b=(-10, 10, 0.5))
output = interactive_plot.children[-1]
output.layout.height = '350px'
interactive_plot
```

///

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `plt.show()` at the end of your function. There was a [github issue about it](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10376)

Try using a `FloatSlider` with `continuous_update=False`. [See here](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html#continuous_update)

```
interactive_plot = interactive(f, m=FloatSlider(min=-10.0, max=10.0,  continuous_update=False), 
                               b=FloatSlider(min=-10, max=10, step=.5, continuous_update=False))
```

Comment: Adding plt.show() still displays a backlog sequence of renderings. I am not sure if there is a good solution to this. But what about the following URL? -> https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Asynchronous.html

Comment: Did you add `plt.show()` at the end of function `f`? This worked for me. Make sure you have upgraded all the packages to their latest versions.

Comment: Yes. I put plt.show() as the last statement in function f. I guess that it is working the way it is supposed to work. Thanks.

Comment: @user2942693 Try my updated solution to avoid continuous updates.

Comment: Setting continuous_update to False does get rid of the live updates. But what I was hoping for is to get live updates, but when they queue up, it would be good if all but the most recent update are removed and that would leave only the penultimate update left pending in the queue.